# boost.python No Python class registered for C++ class std::string

Tags: python, boost

When running a c++ class member function from python, i get this error:
    No Python class registered for C++ class std::string
The member function is:

```
class holiday_calendar {
public:
  const std::string& get_name() const;
  void set_name(const std::string&);
};
```

I have used this exposing code

```
class_<holiday_calendar>("holiday_calendar")
.def("getname", &holiday_calendar::get_name, return_internal_reference<>())
.def("setname", &holiday_calendar::set_name);
```

I can instantiate the object holiday_calendar, I can call setname('SOMENAME') on it
but calling getname() fails with the above error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method get_name returns a `const std::string&`, try this:

```
class_<holiday_calendar>("holiday_calendar")
.def("getname", &holiday_calendar::get_name, return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>())
.def("setname", &holiday_calendar::set_name);
```